# Unable to access Anaconda Environment in R w/ Reticulate

Tags: python, r, anaconda, conda, reticulate

I am having issues selecting a particular Anaconda environment with the reticulate package in R.

What I have been successful with is getting python working with R on my machine using the below code (using R Markdown):

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(reticulate)
use_python("C:/Anaconda3/python.exe")```
````

That's great and all but ideally I would like to use the particular environments that I've created previously within Anaconda. So, this is what I've tried along with the error message:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(reticulate)
use_condaenv(condaenv = 'PFDA', conda = "C:/Anaconda3/Library/bin/conda")```

Error: Specified conda binary 'C:/Anaconda3/Library/bin/conda' does not exist.
````

I have been referencing this documentation [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reticulate/vignettes/versions.html) and it suggests the code should go something like this:

```
use_condaenv(condaenv = "r-nlp", conda = "/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda")
```

However, in my Anaconda3 folder, I don't have a subfolder named bin:
[image]

There's obviously something I am doing wrong here. Potentially, I am not sending R in the right direction to locate conda? Hopefully, someone can point me in the right direction as I've been really excited to implement this in my coding life.

My session specs:

```
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] reticulate_1.13

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.6.2  Matrix_1.2-18   tools_3.6.2    
 [4] yaml_2.2.0      Rcpp_1.0.3      grid_3.6.2     
 [7] knitr_1.26      jsonlite_1.6    xfun_0.11      
[10] png_0.1-7       lattice_0.20-38
```

Comment: I think the Windows Conda is at `Anaconda3/Scripts/conda.exe`.

Comment: @merv That has not worked for me, unfortunately. Any other ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `where conda` to figure out where the Conda binary is. Or search your folders (`Scripts`, `condabin`, etc)

Comment: @merv For some strange reason, your first answer to my question is now working. Just for clarification, this solution worked for me in the end:

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(reticulate)
#use_python("C:/Anaconda3/envs/PFDA/python.exe")
use_condaenv(condaenv = 'PFDA', conda = "C:/Anaconda3/Scripts/conda.exe")
```

Thank you!